# Swashbuckle - How to omit only REST api methods, but not Entities

Tags: swagger, code-generation, swashbuckle

We use swashbuckle to generate client code where we need only model class types, but not methods which are generated to call api. For that we have our own generic implementation. Is there a way how to omit those methods only without omitting model classes?

When I use `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` on all my controllers, my output js file is empty.

For example it generates these methods, which are completly useless for us, only what I need is `Metadata` class type, nothing else.

```
apiGet(): Promise<Metadata> {
    let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/MetadataRepository/Catalog";
    url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

    let options_ = <RequestInit>{
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json", 
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    };

    return this.http.fetch(url_, options_).then((_response: Response) => {
        return this.processApiGet(_response);
    });
}

protected processApiGet(response: Response): Promise<Metadata> {
    const status = response.status;
    let _headers: any = {}; if (response.headers && response.headers.forEach) { response.headers.forEach((v: any, k: any) => _headers[k] = v); };
    if (status === 200) {
        return response.text().then((_responseText) => {
        let result200: any = null;
        let resultData200 = _responseText === "" ? null : JSON.parse(_responseText, this.jsonParseReviver);
        result200 = resultData200 ? Metadata.fromJS(resultData200) : new Metadata();
        return result200;
        });
    } else if (status !== 200 && status !== 204) {
        return response.text().then((_responseText) => {
        return throwException("An unexpected server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
        });
    }
    return Promise.resolve<Metadata>(<any>null);
}
```

Comment: Isn't swagger basically json-schema? If so, there's a bunch of npm packages that convert json-schema directly to typescript types. Makes it very easy, and you can ignore all the swagger garbage.

Comment: Look into IDocumentFilters on swashbuckle, with that you can transform the output to suit your needs